# Логические операции в PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, логические-выражения

проблема у меня возникла с пониманием булевых операций в  python-Pandas и использованием **ИЛИ**.

Почему когда меняю условия местами меняется результат хотя стоит логический оператор **ИЛИ**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1', '2', '3'], 'col_1': [7, 2, 7], 'col_2':[1, 4, 5],'col_3':[8,4,6]})
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
col1=df['col_1']
col2=df['col_2']
col3=df['col_3']

sravn=(col1>col2).item #1 сравнение 
print ('t1',sravn) #1
sravn=(col1>col3).item #2 сравнение
print ('t2',sravn) #2
```

- возвращает 1. `true` `false` `true`
- возвращает 2. `false` `false` `true`
- ожидаемый результат при использовании **ИЛИ**: `true` `false` `true`

```
print ('****-'*10)
sravn=(col1>col2).item or (col1>col3).item 
print (sravn) #1 return true false true
sravn= (col1>col3).item or (col1>col2).item #2 return false false true
print (sravn) #2 return false false true
```

Как видно, результат во втором случае не соответствует  первому. Почему при изменении очередности условий происходит такая замена, мне не понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Вы делаете что-то очень странное, `item` возвращает метод:

```
sravn=(col1>col2).item
print(type(sravn))
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'method'>
```

Что вы делаете с методом (а не с данными) я не очень понимаю, не удивительно, что в итоге что-то странное получается. Работать с `Pandas.Series` нужно так:

```
print ('t1', col1>col2, sep='\n') # на выходе Series
print ('t2', col1>col3, sep='\n') # на выходе Series
print ('****-'*10)
print((col1>col2) | (col1>col3)) # побитовое ИЛИ
print((col1>col3) | (col1>col2)) # побитовое ИЛИ
```

Вывод, результат от перестановки не меняется:

```
t1
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
t2
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****-
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Обратите внимание, что для векторов нужно использовать **побитовое ИЛИ** `|`, а не **логическое ИЛИ** `or`, которое применяется к объектам в целом, а не к частям объекта.

Comment: Спасибо, большое.Причина оказалась именно в том что когда я в первом варианте  когда писал программу использовал or. Программа выдавала вот такую ошибку""" Traceback (most recent call last):
ile "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'''    
      И я начал использовать item.  А оказывается or и | это не совсем одно и тоже. Век живи, век учись!

Comment: @favorite Для одиночных булевых объектов разницы нет, а вот для более сложных объектов, даже для одиночных `int` разница уже есть: `print(2 | 1, 2 or 1) -> 3 2`.

Comment: @favorite Что значит "не прошёл", что пишет? Нет ли в данных `NaN`, кстати? Данные точно числовые?

Comment: Разобрался,  спасибо. Какой то косяк с синтаксисом был.